# "get.output" and "CSV.write" packages in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use a R script(https://csbi.ltdk.helsinki.fi/cn2gealgo/downloads/cnaGenerator.r) from a research paper for a lab project however, it has two functions that I don't recognize:

- get.output
- CSV.write

I tried looking online for any libraries that might include these two functions but to no avail. For some background they are part of a genetic simulation script(so these functions might be in some biological or genetic analysis package).

Here are the lines of code that use these functions(might shed some light on them):

```
# Output
table.out <- as.data.frame(cnaMatrix)
CSV.write(get.output(cf, 'optOut1'), as.data.frame(exprMatrix))
CSV.write(get.output(cf, 'optOut2'), as.data.frame(exprAnnot))

rm(optOut1)
rm(optOut2)
```

Comment: expreMatrix and exprAnnot are data frames and "OptOut1&2" have not been used anywhere else.

Comment: https://anduril.org/pub/api/r/CSV.write.html

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: you are welcome, and welcome to SO. i also couldn't find the get.option() command but i assume it has to do with creating a filepath/filename so you might be able to circumvent it by just following the syntax of CSV.write.

Comment: Sounds good! I'll look into it.